# JavaScript (jQuery) disable checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have a bit of a problem. I have some code, the JS works (at least with the non-CSS modified version), but it fails with the CSS modified version. Wondering if anyone can lend me some help to figure out what went wrong with the implementation of the CSS...

What I want to have happen, is the any of the first 4 chekboxes, if checked, disable all others. But, if any of the other checkboxes (numbers 5 and up) are checked, none are disabled (unless of course someone checks one of the first four).

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
var $inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]', $('#test'));
var $inputs2 = $('input[type=checkbox]', $('#test2'));
$inputs.change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',($this.index() < 4 && this.checked));        
    if($this.index() < 4 && this.checked){
        $inputs.not(this).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
$inputs2.change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $inputs2.not(this).prop('disabled',($this.index() < 4 && this.checked));        
    if($this.index() < 4 && this.checked){
        $inputs2.not(this).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
});
```

The first Div:

```
<div id="test" style="float:left; width:50%">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr><td style="font-size:3px">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <p id="Error" style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff;">Please, enter data</p></tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1" class="css-checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="1" class="css-label">1</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" class="css-checkbox" value="2" />
      <label for="2" class="css-label">2</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3" class="css-checkbox" value="3" />
      <label for="3" class="css-label">3</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4" class="css-checkbox" value="4" />
      <label for="4" class="css-label">4</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="5" name="5" class="css-checkbox" value="5" />
      <label for="5" class="css-label">5</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="6" name="6" class="css-checkbox" value="6" />
      <label for="6" class="css-label">6</label></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My CSS, if needed:

```
<style>
#Error {display: none;}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {display:none;}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {padding-left:20px;height:20px;display:inline-block;line-height:20px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: 0 0;font-size:15px;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {background-position: 0 -20px;}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:disabled + label.css-label {background-position: 0 -40px;}
.css-label{ background-image:url(web-two-style.png);}
</style>
```

The problem is: the following works, and the following was later modified with CSS and I can't figure out what went wrong.

What works:

```
<div id='test'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" id="check1" >first
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" id="check2" >second
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" id="check3" >third
    <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1" id="check4" >fourth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="1" id="check5" >fifth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="1" id="check6" >sixth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="1" id="check7" >seventh
    <input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="1" id="check8" >eight
</div>
```

It gets even odder when I add the code that worked to the same div as the one that doesn't, since it the above non-CSS then works properly and will disable (where appropriate) all the checkboxes regardless of CSS, but when the CSS are checked, all are disabled:

```
<div id="test" style="float:left; width:50%">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr><td style="font-size:3px">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <p id="Error" style="background: #ff0000; color: #fff;">Please, enter data</p></tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1" class="css-checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="1" class="css-label">1</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" class="css-checkbox" value="2" />
      <label for="2" class="css-label">2</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3" class="css-checkbox" value="3" />
      <label for="3" class="css-label">3</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="4" name="4" class="css-checkbox" value="4" />
      <label for="4" class="css-label">4</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="5" name="5" class="css-checkbox" value="5" />
      <label for="5" class="css-label">5</label></td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150px"><input type="checkbox" id="6" name="6" class="css-checkbox" value="6" />
      <label for="6" class="css-label">6</label></td></tr>      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" id="check1" >first
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" id="check2" >second
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" id="check3" >third
    <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1" id="check4" >fourth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="1" id="check5" >fifth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="1" id="check6" >sixth
    <input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="1" id="check7" >seventh
    <input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="1" id="check8" >eight
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are  you using?

Comment: CSS ID's cannot start with a number, classes can, but not IDs, therefore, `<input type="checkbox" id="5" name="5" class="css-checkbox" value="5" />` isn't valid

Comment: Try this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/V8qXd/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.index()` returns the index relative to the **sibling elements**. In your working example the siblings of an `<input>` are the other inputs. In your non-working example the only sibling is the `<label>` element.

In your "odd" example all inputs are siblings again.

In order to make it work anyway you can use `.index(element)`:

```
$inputs.index($this)
```

This returns the index of the input `$this` within the jquery input collection `$inputs`. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GjEHd/).

Comment: So if I'm not to use .index() with the above, then what would be proper? Since I'm not sure it's possible to remove the label from the checkboxes and have the CSS styling still work.

Comment: You can use `.index()` but differently. I have updated the answer and provided a fiddle. Anyway I suggest considering to separate model and view in your future projects. Then you will not have that kind of problems in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the ID's on your input fields, ID's can't start with a number

```
<input type="checkbox" id="5" name="5" class="css-checkbox" value="5" />
```

may cause problems with your JS. I would try something like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="field-5" name="5" class="css-checkbox" value="5" />
```

Comment: That doesn't really fix anything (it's a good thing to note for future reference). It's still just disabling all when **any** checkbox is checked, not just the first four checkboxes doing that...